# Elastic net consistency for time series case

Tags: time-series, references, elastic-net, regularization

I am looking for a paper that proves elastic net consistency (in estimation and model selection) for time series setting (non i.i.d. errors). I have found papers for LASSO and adaptive LASSO but after browsing the web I was not able to find a paper for elastic net.

Comment: Hi, could you provide the links or titles for the papers of LASSO and adaptive LASSO? Thank you!